# Scroll in LinearLayout with Bar Graphic

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a LinearLayout where I add a view "mChartView" (corresponding to a bar chart graphics library aChartEngine).
The problem is that the linear layout fills the screen height, but can not see the full chart legend.
Could anyone tell me how to apply a vertical ScrollView to move the LinearLayout and see the full chart legend?

I tried the following, but does not work:

```
     ScrollView scvista = new ScrollView (this);
     scvista.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         ...
     scvista.addView (mChartView, new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     layout.addView (scvista);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: what exactly happened now , is it crashing or not able to scroll ? may be it is not able to scroll because your chart view overridden scroll view

Comment: What happens is that this does not paint the figure, however, if I remove it from the Scroll, it paint but in the dimensions of the screen and can not see the full legend.

Comment: MChartView himself has a scroll that allows me to move the chart in any direction, even if shifted clicking on the chart legend shifts. Perhaps this feature makes it incompatible put another scroll to scroll the view?

Comment: yep if you put one scrollview to another view get confuse which scroll has to be execute parent scroll or child scroll ..try to override and execute  your chartview scroll to achieve your expectations